# Getting error while sending email through SMTP

Tags: email, message, asp.net-4.0, smtpclient

I am getting following error message while sending email through SMTP service:

[image]

I have following SMTP setting  on my system:

[image]

Operating system: Windows 7 Home Premium

IIS: IIS 7

How can i resolve this problem?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the inner exception and your code, you're trying to send mail via 127.0.0.1.

Removing the line in your code that is setting the smtp host to 127.0.0.1 should cause the site to use the SMTP settings as defined in IIS.

As SMTP settings will usually vary in between server setups, live / test environments, it is usually best to not hard-code SMTP settings such as Host in your code and instead to set the settings via IIS (which actually takes from web.config's section system.net/mailSettings).

**Edit:**

As your web.config doesn't have a mailSettings section, I would assume you took the screenshot from the SMTP Email in IIS7 in the server view. There's a similar section in the website view.

You can manually add the mailSettings to the web.config: I usually do so.

For your setup (ie, storing emails as file in a directory), the following would be needed:

```
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp deliveryMethod="specifiedPickupDirectory">
        <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="c:\inetpub" />
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
```

Note that this wouldn't *send* emails, but just store them in the folder for a SMTP server to pick them up. To send them, you'll need to setup a SMTP server or connect to a third party one like http://sendgrid.com.

Comment: i removed that line(mSmtpClient.Host = "127.0.0.1";) and when i run the application i got another error " The SMTP host was not specified. " what should i do now?actually i am creating a test application using asp.net 4.0 to know the e-mail sending functionality.

Comment: where is your SMTP email screenshot from? Is it from the server or the website view?

Comment: might be helpful if you could show your web.config, especially the system.net/mailSettings section. If it doesn't exist it should be added.

Comment: this screenshot is from IIS 7 on my system

Comment: yeah system.net/mailSettings section is not exist in web.config.can u please let me know what element should i have to add regarding this.

Comment: Updated the answer to have an example mailSettings section.

Comment: Now it's working fine.I am really thankful to you for helping me on each an every step to resolve my problem.thanks a lot.+1

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you look at the exception detail, including any inner exception.  To hazard a guess, maybe you don't have permission to write to C:\Inetpub.

Comment: Inner exception is " Unable to connect to the remote server "

Comment: Inner exception is " {"A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network 127.0.0.1:25"} "